# Room Database: Crash on RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity()

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

I've got a legacy app that's using Room that's crashing as soon as the first database query is executed, no matter what the query is.

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.someco.android.nettasks.PushQueueService@24ccdca6 with Intent { cmp=com.someco.android/.nettasks.PushQueueService }: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Cannot execute this statement because it might modify the database but the connection is read-only.
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3439)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:181)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
   Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Cannot execute this statement because it might modify the database but the connection is read-only.
      at io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.throwIfStatementForbidden(SQLiteConnection.java:1091)
      at io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:755)
      at io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:764)
      at io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:71)
      at io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1867)
      at io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1808)
      at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.createMasterTableIfNotExists(RoomOpenHelper.java:131)
      at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity(RoomOpenHelper.java:107)
      at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.java:100)
      at io.requery.android.database.sqlite.RequerySQLiteOpenHelperFactory$CallbackSQLiteOpenHelper.onOpen(RequerySQLiteOpenHelperFactory.java:67)
      at io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:283)
      at io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:174)
      at io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:44)
      at com.someco.android.dmodel.OurDB.writableDb(OurDB.java:363)
      at com.someco.android.nettasks.PushQueueService.startExecution(PushQueueService.java:202)
      at com.someco.android.nettasks.PushQueueService.onStartCommand(PushQueueService.java:157)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3422)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:181)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

From my investigations on the debugger, what's happening is that there's some sort of racing issue with regard to calls to `sqlite3_stmt_readonly()` in sqlite itself. This is the actual query that causes the crash, from `RoomOpenHelper#createMastertableIfNotExists`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)
```

In `RoomOpenHelper#onCreate`, the table is created successfully. A statement seems to be compiled two times and checked for read-only status those two times:

- Once in `SQLiteProgram`'s constructor (via `SQLiteStatement`)
- Once in `SQLiteConnection#executeForChangedRowCount`

What happens is that the connection fetched for the first one is opened with more permissive permissions (`6`, for me - `1` is the bit that denotes read-only status), and it's correctly evaluated to not be read-only. That means that the connection for the second statement compilation is requested with read-only flags (`5`, for me). The crash happens because for some reason, the query is evaluated to not be read-only once again.

I'm at a total loss for this one. Why does this crash? How is the same statement read-only sometimes and not read-only other times?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that room `1.0.0` does not support the Write-Ahead Log. I removed a line that enabled it in the app:

```
db.getOpenHelper().setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(true);
```

The WAL is supported in version `1.1.0-alpha2`. After trying out the new alpha, everything worked, so the change log pointed me to the  answer.  I've an [example project](https://github.com/MisterRager/RoomV1WALCrash/tree/master) with a brief write-up of the issue.